# Elasticsearch / Kibana Error : out of range of long

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana, unsigned-integer

Am getting the following error :

```
WARN Can not index event (status=400):
{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse
[ftrace.inode]","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Numeric
value (9223372036856872997) out of range of long (-9223372036854775808
- 9223372036854775807)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@253c6f54;
line: 1, column: 911]"}
```

The Actual problem :
I have a variable of type `unsigned int 64`, But I did not find any data type in Elasticsearch which supports this that can be used in JSON template. Currently I'm using `long` but it isn't able to handle as value is more bigger than that.

JSON Template :

```
        "fileid": {
          "type": "long"      
        },
```

Beater code :

```
           FileId   uint64 `json:"#FileId"
```

Requirement :
              Using JSON template I should be able to dump the unsigned int 64 value to Kibana using ES. I just need any unsigned int 64 supportive datatype .

```
Value of field id : 9223372036856872997  , 9223372036856873004
```

Comment: I think there is an open issue about this in order to support BigIntegers: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17006

Comment: You could transform it to string before indexing as a workaround